# Fast algorithm to calculate delta of two list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have two list of album names, ordered by some score.

```
albums_today = ['album1', 'album2', 'album3']
albums_yesterday = ['album2', 'album1', 'album3']
```

How can I calculate the change of list order and get something like

```
{'album1':1, 'album2':-1, 'album3':0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
D = dict((title, rank) for rank, title in enumerate(albums_yesterday))
for rank, title in enumerate(albums_today):
    D[title] = D[title] - rank
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> albums_today = ['album1', 'album2', 'album3']
>>> albums_yesterday = ['album2', 'album1', 'album3']
>>> D = dict((k,v) for v,k in enumerate(albums_yesterday))
>>> dict((k,D[k]-v) for v,k in enumerate(albums_today))
{'album1': 1, 'album3': 0, 'album2': -1}
```

In Python2.7 or Python3 it can be written even more simply

```
>>> albums_today = ['album1', 'album2', 'album3']
>>> albums_yesterday = ['album2', 'album1', 'album3']
>>> D = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(albums_yesterday)}
>>> {k:D[k]-v for v,k in enumerate(albums_today)}
{'album1': 1, 'album3': 0, 'album2': -1}
```

Comment: @gnibbler How does your solution compare to @TokenMacGuy in terms of speed and memory usage?

Comment: @Satoru.Logic can you run those two solutions on your dataset and tell us the relative speeds?  (TokenMacGuy vs. gnibbler.)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/711272 here it is. sorry if i did any of that incorrectly, i don't really know python

Comment: Python wins again -- most efficient solution is also the easiest to write. +1.

Comment: @kaizer.se: I bet it's due to the efficiency of list comprehensions with regard to explicit loops.

Answer (score 3):

you could also use the same algorithm as i wrote above and just use a single hashmap.

```
def findDelta1(today,yesterday):
 results = {}
 ypos = 0
 for i,title in enumerate(today):
      if title in results:
           results[title] = results[title] - i
      else:
           for ypos in xrange(ypos,len(yesterday)):
                if yesterday[ypos] == title:
                     results[title] = ypos - i
                     ypos = ypos + 1
                     break
                else:
                     results[yesterday[ypos]] = ypos
 return results
```

still O(N), potentially faster and less RAM than my version above.

Comment: this actually is a potentially large speed improvement also in cases where the list only changes a small amount. closer to N and not 2N as before.

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
def delta(a, b):
    rank_a = dict((k, v) for v, k in enumerate(a))
    rank_b = enumerate(b)
    return dict((k, rank_a[k]-i) for i, k in rank_b)
```

which only creates a single dict to look things up into.

Well, as long as every entry in both lists are present exactly once each, then we know that once we look a key up in the rank_a collection, we don't need it anymore.  We can delete it.  Also, to save space, we don't have to populate that collection until the moment a particular key is needed.

```
class LookupOnce:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.cache = {}
        self.seq = iter(seq)
    def get(self, key):
        if key in self.cache:
            value = self.cache[key]
            del self.cache[key]
            return value
        for v,k in self.seq:
            if k == key:
                return v
            self.cache[k] = v
        raise KeyError


def delta(a, b):
    rank_a = LookupOnce(enumerate(a))
    rank_b = enumerate(b)
    result = {}
    for i, k in rank_b:
        result[k] = i - rank_a.get(k)
    return result
```

Comment: :) I'm experimenting about this algorithm. Still trying to find something better.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def transform(albums):
...     return dict((album, i) for i, album in enumerate(albums))
... 
>>> def show_diffs(album1, album2):
...     album_dict1, album_dict2  = transform(album1), transform(album2)
...     for k, v in sorted(album_dict1.iteritems()):
...         print k, album_dict2[k] - v
... 
>>> albums_today = ['album1', 'album2', 'album3']
>>> albums_yesterday = ['album2', 'album1', 'album3']
>>> show_diffs(albums_today, albums_yesterday)
album1 1
album2 -1
album3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

well, depending on what the sizes of your lists are, there are a number of different approaches. without knowing how big your datasets are, i'd suggest that the simplest (perhaps unnecessarily optimized) method is something like:

```
albums_yesterday_lookup = new HashMap();
differences = new HashMap();
foreach(albums_yesterday as position => album_title)
    albums_yesterday_lookup.put(album_title,position);

foreach(albums_today as position => album_title)
    differences.put(album_title, albums_yesterday_lookup.get(album_title) - position);
```

which runs as O(N).

Comment: This is the algorithm I'm using currently, I just wonder if there are some other algorithms that consumes less space.

Comment: you could trade RAM consumption for a lot more steps if you switched to an O(N^2) and do it without the HashMap. just replace the `albums_yesterday_lookup.get(album_title)` with `albums_yesterday.find(album_title)` (where .find() would return the position of the given album title)

Comment: This would most likely be an unwise optimization.  If the lists are large enough that memory consumption is substantial, the asymptotic cost is going to be even worse...

Comment: yeah, i don't like the .find() either. but again, without knowing where the bottleneck is, "pre-optimizing" is rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

**New and Improved and not O(n<sup>2</sup>)**: But still slower than two of the other answers.

The only advantage of this solution is memory savings. It avoids building a big dict and instead stores only what is necessary at the time.  TokenMacGuy's second solution does this as well but this is slightly faster.

```
def get_deltas_aas(today, yesterday):
    deltas = {}
    for (new_rank, new_album), (old_rank, old_album) in \
            itertools.izip(enumerate(today), enumerate(yesterday)):
        if old_album in deltas:
            #Believe it or not, this is faster than deltas.pop(old_album) + old_rank
            yield (old_album, deltas[old_album] + old_rank)
            del deltas[old_album]    
        else:
            deltas[old_album] = old_rank

        if new_album in deltas:
            yield (new_album, deltas[new_album] - new_rank)
            del deltas[new_album]
        else:
            deltas[new_album] = -new_rank
```

Here's some timing results for most of the answers here (all of the ones in Python unless I missed something). `dict` ordering is in effect. If anybody wants me to change their code in any way, just ping me.

```
get_deltas_token1: 1.08131885529 msecs
get_deltas_gnibbler: 1.06443881989 msecs
get_deltas_tyler: 1.61993408203 msecs
get_deltas_token2: 1.52525019646 msecs
get_deltas_hughdbrown: 3.27240777016 msecs
get_deltas_aas: 1.39379096031 msecs
```

The code I used to do the timing is [here](https://gist.github.com/711343). I'm pleased with the timing framework I tossed together for it on top of timeit. Should be useful in the future after refactoring the code for running the tests.

Comment: But this is of O(n^2) complexity.